# Why Select2 framework can not find some unicode character?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-select2

I use select2.js in mu web site .Language of my website is persian .I fill select element with this option

```
<select name="TrainDeparture" class="full-width select2" id="TrainDeparture">
    <option  value="165">كرج</option>   
</select>
```

js:

```
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    $.fn.select2.locales['fa'] = {
        formatMatches: function (matches) { return matches + " نتیجه موجود است، کلیدهای جهت بالا و پایین را برای گشتن استفاده کنید."; },
        formatNoMatches: function () { return "نتیجه‌ای یافت نشد."; },
        formatInputTooShort: function (input, min) { var n = min - input.length; return "لطفاً " + n + " نویسه بیشتر وارد نمایید"; },
        formatInputTooLong: function (input, max) { var n = input.length - max; return "لطفاً " + n + " نویسه را حذف کنید."; },
        formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) { return "شما فقط می‌توانید " + limit + " مورد را انتخاب کنید"; },
        formatLoadMore: function (pageNumber) { return "در حال بارگیری موارد بیشتر…"; },
        formatSearching: function () { return "در حال جستجو…"; }
    };

    $.extend($.fn.select2.defaults, $.fn.select2.locales['fa']);
})(jQuery);
$('.select2').select2();
```

When I type in search box of select2

> ك

character it show message that *no result found* but this is wrong .

> I add arabic language to my keyboard and retest . In this case select2
>   found words currently . Now How can i fix this?

**[jsbin link](http://jsbin.com/zexeva/edit?html,js,output)**

Comment: what is your page encoding? JavaScript (which is used at select2 library) understands utf8 / utf16 only. Your page encoding must be compliant with that (see your page `head` section). Page encoding is important here because the data is coming to JS from a `select` html element, so the source of the data is HTML => encoding is important

Comment: I use     <meta charset="utf-8"> in head section

Comment: could you try to go with utf16?

Comment: I test   <meta charset="utf-16"> but does not work.

Comment: would be nice if you can create a fiddle which reproduces the problem. Probably during the process you would already find out what is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In persian and arabic language exist number character that write same  but code of this characters are not same! suach as :

`ك` is arabic character

`ک` is persian character

I change this character to persian and solve.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I created a custom matcher.

```
function customMatcher (params, data){
    // Always return the object if there is nothing to compare
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return data;
    }

    if (data.children && data.children.length > 0) {
        // Clone the data object if there are children
        // This is required as we modify the object to remove any non-matches
        var match = $.extend(true, {}, data);

        // Check each child of the option
        for (var c = data.children.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
            var child = data.children[c];

            var matches = customMatcher(params, child);
            // console.log(matches);

            // If there wasn't a match, remove the object in the array
            if (matches == null) {
                match.children.splice(c, 1);
            }
        }

        // If any children matched, return the new object
        if (match.children.length > 0) {
            return match;
        }

        // If there were no matching children, check just the plain object
        return customMatcher(params, match);
    }

    var original = data.text.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toUpperCase();
    var term = params.term.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toUpperCase();

    // Check if the text contains the term
    if (original.indexOf(term) > -1) {
        return data;
    }

    // If it doesn't contain the term, don't return anything
    return null;
}
$('select').select2({
    matcher: customMatcher
});
```

The main difference to the original one is how the diacritics are removed.

```
var original = data.text.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toUpperCase();
var term = params.term.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").toUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

As hmahdavi said, the best way to handle is, change the characters while filling the `select2` object. I my myself replace the 'ي' with 'ی' in controller while filling Model in asp.net mvc.
example code in asp.net mvc:
While filling project list from datatable:

```
var prjList = (from x in dtPrjList.AsEnumerable()

select new ProjectViewModels
{
  Id = x.Field<Int64>("HdrId"),
  Name = x.Field<String>("PrjName").Replace('ي','ی'),
  Code = x.Field<String>("AccNo"),
}).ToList();
```

If you are using model, change chars in server side.